# Declare Object Inside or Outside For Loop - Spring

Tags: java, spring

Rookie question here - I have a method that accepts an array of User IDs via the Spring CrudRepository `findOne()` method and sets a common attribute. This is my current implementation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setUsersActive/{ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setActive(@PathVariable Long[] ids) {
for(Long id : ids) {
    User user = userRepo.findOne(id);
    user.setActive("Y");    
    userRepo.save(user);    
}
```

This method could potentially accept thousands of IDs within the array - Would it make any difference in performance if I were to declare the `User` object outside of the for loop like so?

```
User user;
for(Long id : ids) {
    user = userRepo.findOne(id);
    user.setActive("Y");        
}
```

Any input is appreciated thanks

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Always make the scope of your variables as narrow as possible. Not for performance, but for correctness, and easy refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to use the last saved `User` object outside of that loop, there is no reason to declare it outside of it, it limits that variable's scope. As far as performance, let Java optimize it for you during compile.

Answer (score 1):

No,propably it will translate to exactly the same byte code,don't waste time on things like that,the JVM will make all kind of strange optimizations to make your code as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good programming practice to **not declare local variables before their use**.

Declaring local variables without using them immediately may unnecessarily increase their scope. This decreases readability, and can increases unwanted errors.

From a performance perspective there is no difference because moving the declaration of User outside the loop doesn't generate earlier the object.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it would, I would declare it out of the loop, it is more efficent. Otherwise the garbage collector must delete whole objects and if you declare it before a loop you save a little RAM usage. Because of setting only the reference to an new object.

Comment: Both versions create as many objects in memory, and the garbage collector has the same number of objects to collect in both versions.

Comment: The garbage collector gets called only when it has objects to remove from the heap,the space of an object will be swiped by the gc only when there are no more references to this object,in the op's code userRepo still holds the references.